# font-variant in Microsoft Edge - Canvas 2D

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to render some text in small-caps in a 2D canvas in Edge but it doesn't work: the text isn't small-caps even though the font property is correct and includes small-caps. I tried to reproduce the problem with the simplest canvas I could think of but I still had it. The render is the same on Internet Explorer 11.

[Firefox and Edge side-by-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfh2m.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work in IE9?

Comment: *Confirming*: Chrome & FF support `small-caps` while IE & Edge do not. The workaround is a bit hackish: Use `context.measureText` to layout a beginning letter in a larger font and the remaining letters in a smaller font.

Comment: Dam MS when you do `ctx.font = "small-caps 16px Arial"; if(ctx.font !== "small-caps 16px Arial"){ console.log("bad font");}` it does not catch it accepting the small-caps as part of a good font description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does in fact appear to be a bug with *small-caps* font variants and the 2D rendering context in Microsoft Edge. I'm working on [a few tests right now](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/mt5hts6w/) to better understand the scope of this issue, but I will be filing a bug for our team to evaluate.

Thank you for sharing this, and I hope to report back with an update soon.

```
/* Above link points to tests on jsfiddle.net */
```